# Couette flow with infinite depth

Tags: partial-differential-equations, physics, fluid-dynamics

Consider a fluid below $x$ axis or $xy$ plane. Its top layer starts to move with velocity $v$ at and after time $t_0$.
If the flow is not fully developed and evolving from standing water, I receive $v_x=0$ from continuity equation due to zero velocity in $y$ direction (and $z$ in 3D case). Which corresponds to fully developed flow since the acceleration is zero.

$$\nabla \cdot v = 0
\\v_t + (v \cdot \nabla) v = -(1/\rho) \nabla p + \nu \Delta v$$

Task itself was to calculate velocity at certain level $h$ below the surface after given time $t_1$. (Pressure at the surface is atmospheric).

I ended up reducing system to 1D heat equation whose solution is implicit.

Could one advise on what I’m doing wrong?

Comment: This might be better suited for Physics or Engineering Stack Exchange. Also, without providing any equations it's hard to get where you are stuck.

Comment: Updated with system, idk  PDE thought suitable here  @Dan Doe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let the axes be oriented so that the fluid on the $xy$-plane moves impulsively at $t = 0+$ with velocity $U$ in the positive $x$-direction and the positive $y$-axis points into the body of fluid.

An analytical solution can be obtained assuming unsteady, unidirectional flow with one non-vanishing velocity component $u$ in the $x$-direction. The continuity equation requires that $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = 0$. Assuming the fluid is bounded by an infinite planar surface, we have that $u(y,t)$ is a function only of $y$ and $t$, and the Navier-Stokes equations and boundary conditions reduce to

$$\tag{*}\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = \nu \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2}, \\  u(0,t) = U \,\,\text{ for }\,\, t \geqslant 0,\\ u(y,t) \to 0 \text{ as  }y \to \infty,$$

where  $\nu = \mu/\rho$ is the kinematic viscosity.

We can solve with a similarity transformation where

$$u(y,t) = f(\eta), \quad \eta = \frac{y}{\sqrt{\nu t}}$$

Then we have

$$\frac{\partial u }{\partial t}= - f'(\eta)\frac{y}{2 \sqrt{\nu}t^{3/2}}=  - \frac{1}{2t}\eta f'(\eta),\\\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\nu t}}f'(\eta),\\\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\nu t}}f''(\eta)\frac{1}{\sqrt{\nu t}} = \frac{1}{\nu t}f''(\eta)$$

Substituting for $u$ and its partial derivatives in (*) and canceling the $1/t$ factors , we get the second-order linear ordinary differential equation and conditions

$$f''(\eta) + \frac{1}{2}\eta f'(\eta) = 0,\\f(0) = U ,\\ f(\eta) \to 0 \,\, \text{ as } \, \, \eta \to \infty$$

It is not difficult to solve this by separating variables and integrating twice, yielding the solution

$$u = U \text{ erfc} \left(\frac{\eta}{2}\right) = U \text{ erfc} \left(\frac{y}{\sqrt{4\nu t}}\right),$$

where the complementary error function is given by

$$\text{erfc}(z) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_z^\infty e^{-t^2} \, dt$$

Comment: Thanks, I also got ans in terms of erf but the problem how to calculate velocity at distance from surface after certain time, solution seems implicit

Comment: @2Napasa:  What is implicit here? The velocity at depth $h$ and time $t_1$ is $u(h,t_1) = U \text{erfc}(\frac{h}{\sqrt{4\nu t_1}})$.  You just need to be able to evaluate the complementary error function.

Comment: My bad, apologies

Comment: @2Napasa: No problem. You're welcome.

Comment: I tried with separation ended up with $a+b e^-(z)$ where a b are from BC

Comment: but had issue that it has to be expressed in terms of $du/dt$ which is unknown

Comment: Strange, got second order DE is $\nu f'' + 0.5 \eta f' = 0$, nvm used $\eta = y/\sqrt{t}$

Comment: your erfc boundary seem to be z to infty instead of 0 to z

Comment: That is how erfc is defined: $erfc(z) = 1- erf(z)$ and  $erf(z) =1-\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_z^\infty e^{-t^2} \, dt =  \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^z e^{-t^2} \, dt $.  We need $Uy,t) \to 0$ as $y \to \infty$ and this holds because $erfc(\eta/2) \to 0$ as $\eta \to \infty$.

Comment: I really don't understand what you are asking with regard to $a +be^-(z)$.

Comment: Thank you! Was only able to find the integral using numerical script. Looks there is no analytic solution. Is this right?

Comment: Yes — this is a special function related to the Gaussian distribution that cannot be evaluated in terms of elementary functions.  You should be able to get numerical values directly with Wolfram alpha.